# Adding lyrics and/or chords as written text along a track in GarageBand 10

Tags: garage-band

I am using **GarageBand 10**, and I would like to add some written notes, along a track (an analog track, imported from an aoudio file), to mark where the **chord changes** occur. Similarly, I would like to add **lyrics**, along the track.
Is there a way? either in the same track, or as an additional "comments" track?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. You have a workaround to add lyrics to the score, but not to an audio file. But it could be easy with Audacity, using the markers.

Answer (score 1):

For the vocals; I just take a screenshot of the score and below notes I write the lyrics. It worked for me on this way because I didn't find any other option.